# Align items in same rows dynamically using css Grid

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, css-grid

I'm running into an issue trying to make the following example works : [Screen using Chrome debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg4Tr.png)

I would like to align my title blocks with my adresses, in fact I'd like adresses start at rows number 1.

Here is the simple code I run :

**CSS**

```
#lawyerOfficeLinksContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.lawyerContract {
    grid-column: 1/2;
}

.lawyerDomiciliation{
    grid-column: 2/3;
}
```

**HTML(using Razor)**

```
<div id="lawyerOfficeLinksContainer">
        @foreach(var contract in Model.LawyerConsultModel.LawyerContractsList.Rows)
        {
            <text>
                <div class="lawyerContract">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <div>
                        <b><label>Name :</label></b>
                        <span>Test Name</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </text>
        }
        @foreach (var dom in Model.LawyerConsultModel.LawyerDomiciliationsList.Rows)
        {
            <text>
                <div class="lawyerDomiciliation">
                    <label>Adress :</label>
                    <p>Test</p>
                </div>
            </text>
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo:

html:

```
<div id="lawyerOfficeLinksContainer">
    <div class="left">
        @foreach(var contract in Model.LawyerConsultModel.LawyerContractsList.Rows)
        {
            <text>
                <div>
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <div>
                        <b><label>Name :</label></b>
                        <span>Test Name</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </text>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        @foreach (var dom in Model.LawyerConsultModel.LawyerDomiciliationsList.Rows)
        {
            <text>
                <div>
                    <label>Adress :</label>
                    <p>Test</p>
                </div>
            </text>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
 #lawyerOfficeLinksContainer {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }

    .left {
        grid-column: 1/2;
    }

    .right {
        grid-column: 2/2;
    }
```

result:
[image]